# How to add tags to Cloudwatch log group using boto3?

Tags: python-2.7, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Trying to add tags to `cloudwatchLog` group using `ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI` service using boto3.
Code seems to be executing with out errors but don't see the tags being added.
How to add tags to `cloudwatchLog` group?

Code:

```
log_group=[]
client = boto3.client('logs')
client_api=boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')

 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in response_iterator:
        for grp in page['logGroups']:
            log_group.append(str(grp['arn']))
    client_api.tag_resources(
        ResourceARNList=log_group,
        Tags={
            'Header1':'value1',
            'Header2':'value2',
            'header3':'value3'}
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here.

1. Print the response of `tag_resources` API, it could contain messages that will point you in the right direction.
2. You're using the newer `tag_resources` API. This API is built on top of older, per resource, APIs. Like [tag_log_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.tag_log_group) API in this case. This means your lambda will need permissions on `tag:TagResources` and on `logs:TagLogGroup`.
3. You are sending ARNs that you got by calling `describe_log_groups`. These ARNs will be of the form `arn:aws:logs:REGION:ACCOUNT:log-group:LOG_GROUP_NAME:*`. Since the underline [tag_log_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.tag_log_group) API works with log groups names and not ARNs, you need to drop the last `:*` from the ARN so the correct log group name can be extracted.
4. I'm not 100% sure you can even see tags on log groups in the UI. You may need to call [list_tags_log_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.list_tags_log_group) API to verify the tags are there.

Comment: I have removed ':*' in arn and tried to add. It worked.Also, able to get the tags for log group using 'resourcetaggingapi' paginator('get_resources').But, i can't see the tags in UI.